# Can Json save object references or does it only copy values?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I am building an Android app that saves some objects in a database. Some attributes of my objects are serialized in Gson's Json first. Here's the issue, I have a `Workout` class

```
public class Workout {
    private UUID mId;
    private Date mStartDate;
    private Date mEndDate;
    private List<PerformedExercise> mPerformedExercises;
    private String mNotes;
}
```

and an Exercise class

```
public class Exercise {
    private UUID mId;
    private String mName;
    private String mCategory;
    private List<PerformedExercise> mPerformedExercises;
}
```

Both of these objects will be stored in a database. Everything but the `List<PerformedExercise>`
will be saved as regular, primitive types. The list will be serialized in Json first and then stored. The problem is that instances of `Exercise` and `Workout` can share the same `PerformedExercise` in the `List<PerformedExercise>`. In my code, they are references to instances of `PerformedExercise`. I need to be able to keep references to these `PerformedExercise` when my code is Serialized and Deserialized. How is this possible?

Comment: How would you even know that the List is still in that memory location? If the App is stopped or restarted, or the list is garbage collected, it's not going to be in that location anymore (most likely)

Comment: When people start wanting to save references it always indicates that the serialization approach will be bespoke to that use case. Either change your  data model or crank out bespoke code.

Comment: @John Hey man thank you for your reply. What do you think about this: In both my classes, I would have a list of UUIDs for my PerformedExercises. I would also have an instance of a database of PerformedExercises. I would have a method in each of these classes for adding, removing, and updating my PerformedExercises that would update the list of UUIDs and the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need create separate WorkoutDB model for Database where instead list of objects you will
contain a list of primitive types like a list of kids Exercises

for example:

```
public class WorkoutDB {
    private UUID mId;
    private Date mStartDate;
    private Date mEndDate;

    //list of Ids
    private List<String> mIdsExercises;
    private String mNotes;
}
```

So after getting Workout from base you can get all exercises via ids list.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So basically I would have a list of IDs for my PerformedExercises in my classes and I would also have a database of all PerformedExercises? To get my PerformedExercises for the instances of the classes I would query the database of PerformedExercises with the ids in the list?

Comment: you can just iteration your ids list and get each PerformedExercises via next id in order